# Help me open my safe

Tags: number-sequence

**Edit:** The first version of this puzzle was apparently too hard. After a days worth of back and forth, I am consolidating all hints, answer attempts, and comments into a restated puzzle here from the point where we collectively had gotten to. We now have actually arrived at the original version of the puzzle before I posted it, which I changed because I thought it would be too easy. I guess we'll find out...
(If you want to see the previous harder version of the puzzle, look back at the edit history.)

**Restated Puzzle:**

My safe has an 8 digit code. Since I was worried I would forget it, I wrote four other 8 digit codes on a piece of paper and taped it to the door of the safe. The code to my safe is the next number in this sequence:

```
21600991
10707681
40706771
10019491
```

Can you help me figure out the 8 digit code to open my safe?

Hint:

> People who live in the largest countries in the world may find this question easier to solve than those who don't.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37504/discussion-on-question-by-ttt-help-me-open-my-safe). (It showed up via auto-flag, but in the future, if you'd like, just flag it yourself!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Eureka!

The trick is to

> read the numbers backwards.  This gives you 19900612, 18670701, 17760704, 19491001.  When read as YYYYMMDD dates, these correspond to the national holidays of Russia, Canada, the USA, and China, respectively.  That's the four largest countries in the world, by area.  Next in line is Brazil, whose declaration of independence was on 18220907.

Thus, your safe combination is

> 70902281

Comment: Well done! That's exactly right.

Comment: @TTT great puzzle!

Answer (score 2):

This is just a continuation of my previous guess, might not be the real answer because it can't explain hint 1

> 83034934

Since

> From Hint 4, its obvious that the password is '123456' 
>  Since he "added" the password to the paper code, the resulting numbers are 
>  21600991
> 10707681
>  40706771
> 10019491 
>  which give the answer of 83034934

Edit:

> From  [this website](https://www.skyhighnetworks.com/cloud-security-blog/you-wont-believe-the-20-most-popular-cloud-service-passwords/!), its seems 123456 is the most common password.

Comment: I thought the password would be obvious from Hint 4, but apparently I was wrong. Sorry, that is not the correct password.

Comment: I also wonder why would the above password correspond to hint 1 ... I will re-think.

Comment: @Matthew Lau: The password could also result by some kind of majority vote from these four numbers.

Comment: Is it correct that Hint 2 concerns Russia and Canada? (people who live in largest countries in the world)

Comment: @Gamow - yes, among others.

Comment: @MatthewLau - the answer is pretty far off, but you applied the password correctly.

Comment: @TTT: Does that include China and the US?

Comment: @dan04 - it does.

Answer (score 0):

This is my best guess:

> password

Reasoning:

> Most places I look say that it is the 1st or 2nd most common password. Also in hint 3 you said "All you know is that it's probably numeric" which seemed strange to mention unless it wasn't really numeric. This guess may be a long shot, but I'm really trying to listen to hint 4 on this one.

Second Guess:

> 12345678

Comment: Can you give reasoning for the second guess?

Comment: If you read the other answers and comments you'll see that the password has already been determined, and now the puzzle is to solve the remaining number sequence. See Matthew Lau's answer as a good starting point.

Comment: I just updated the question with more information to clear this up.